# É possivel insert verificando os campos?

Tags: php, sql

Meu problema é: "Eu tenho um `array` que armazena dados de `duas combos`. Em uma `combo` eu adiciono **"P"** e depois o valor digitado. **Ex: P111111111**. E no outro eu adiciono no inicio **"S"** e fica **S11111111**. Mas em minha tabela do banco eu tenho os campos separados para o **P** e para o **S**, e assim gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um `insert` para verificar se a primeira letra é **P** ou **S**, para assim poder inserir em seus devidos campos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sim... um modo de fazer isso em php:

```
$str = $_ POST ou GET['sua variavel']

$posição1 = str_split($str,1);

switch ($posição1) {
    case 'P': //Faz o que voce quer;
    break;
    case 'S': //Faz o que voce quer;
    break;
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @ MarceloBonifazio, era isso mesmo que eu precisava!

Answer (score 2):

Outra maneira de extrair o primeiro caracter de um string é usar [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$char = substr($str, 0, 1); //copia um caracter da posição zero
```

ou passar o indice zero da variável

```
$char = $str[0];
```

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta @ perdeu. Junto com a que o @ MarceloBonifazio deu, consigo fazer certinho o que necessito fazer!